# SQL - using 'HAVING' with 'EXISTS' without using 'GROUP BY'

Tags: sql, exists, having

Using 'HAVING' without 'GROUP BY' is not allowed:

```
SELECT *
FROM products
HAVING unitprice > avg(unitprice)
```

*Column 'products.UnitPrice' is invalid in the HAVING clause because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.*

But when placing the same code under 'EXISTS' - no problems:

```
SELECT *
FROM products p
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM products
              HAVING p.unitprice > avg(unitprice))
```

Can you please explain why?

Comment: Which database product are you using? This feels like some goofy crap that would happen in mysql. My guess is that the average aggregation of your subquery's `products.unitprice` is inferred since it's the only column being used in the subquery's `products` table (the other mentioned columns are `p.unitprice` and `1` neither of which are in that table). Where in your first query you are asking for both the average aggregate AND the non-aggregated `unitprice` in the same condition statement without using a window function.

Comment: "Using 'HAVING' without 'GROUP BY' is not allowed" -- That might be your impression but that's wrong. It is not allowed to use a column (or any expression using such a column) in the `HAVING` clause that isn't either an argument to an aggregation function in the `HAVING` clause or listed in the `GROUP BY` clause. Same goes for the columns listed after `SELECT` BTW. E.g. try `SELECT avg(unitprice)
FROM products
HAVING avg(unitprice) > 0;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well the error is clear in first query UnitPrice is not part of aggregation nor group by
whereas in your second query you are comparing p.unitprice from table "products p" which doesn't need to be part of aggregation or group by , your second query is equivalent to :

```
select * from products p
where p.unitprice > (select avg(unitprice) FROM products)
```

which maybe this is more clear , that sql caculate avg(unitprice) then compares it with unitprice column from product.

Answer (score 0):

`HAVING` filters *after* aggregation according to the SQL standard and in most databases.

Without a `GROUP BY`, there is still aggregation.

But in your case, you simply want a subquery and `WHERE`:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM products p
WHERE p.unitprice > (SELECT AVG(p2.unitprice) FROM products p2);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem comes from the columns you select :

```sql
SELECT *
```

and

```sql
SELECT 1
```

Unlike ordinary functions that are evaluated at each row, aggregate functions are computed once the whole dataset is processed, which means that in theory (at least without a GROUP BY statement), you can't select both aggregate and regular functions in a same column set (even if some DBMS still tolerate this).

It's easier to see when considering SUM(). You're not supposed to have an access to the total of a column before all rows have been returned, which prevents you to write something like `SELECT price,SUM(price)`, for instance.

`GROUP BY`, now, enables you to regroup your rows according to a given criteria (actually, a bunch of columns), which makes these aggregate functions to be computed at the end of each of these groups instead of the whole dataset. Therefore, since all the column specified in `GROUP BY` are supposed to be the same for a given group, you're allowed to include them in your global `SELECT` statement.

This leads us to the actual failure cause: on first query, you select all columns. On the second one, you select none: only the constant `1`, which is not part of the table itself.